# Get multimedia component byte array using Tridion Anguilla framework?

Tags: tridion

Is it possible to get a byte array of an image stored in Tridion using the Anguilla JavaScript API?  I would like to display an image in a GUI extension popup window.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is by simply loading the MMC using a URL like this:

```
http://<hostname>/WebUI/Editors/CME/icon.png?uri=tcm:2-1151
```

If you use that approach the actual loading of the bytes has nothing to do with Tridion anymore: you're just loading an image from a URL.

You'll probably want to construct the URL in JavaScript, so start with something like this (which I shamelessly copied from the source code):

```js
p.multimediaUrl = $display.getMultimediaHandlerPath() + "?uri={0}";
```

### Update

As usual the Mozilla Developer Connection has a great [example on loading binary data with XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Handling_binary_data). Applied to this situation, I seem to get the data with this snippet:

```js
var arraybuffer;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", $display.getMultimediaHandlerPath() + '?uri==tcm%3A2-1151', true);
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer"; 
xhr.onload = function(e) {
  arraybuffer = xhr.response; // not responseText
}
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Does it use the original image size?

Comment: From my testing it does return the image in its original size, but you can give it parameters to control the size. An example I grabbed from my server: `http://<hostname>/WebUI/Editors/CME/icon.png?target=view&maxwidth=320&maxheight=200&uri=tcm%3A2-1151&mode=thumb&modified=2012-07-23T21:14:39`. I found some extra parameters by searching the source code for `getMultimediaHandlerPath()`, such as `target=download`.